What's the difference between these two equations $E=F/q$ and $E=k_cq/r^2$ for the electric field?
on my list of equations for AP physics II i have both equations set equal to electric fields. they obviously equal different things and i was wondering if someone could tell me how they are different!
$$E=F/q$$
$$E=k_cq/r^2$$

It is two different things.
The first one is general: it tells you that if you know the electric force $F$ on a charge $q$ at some point in space, and the electric force is the only one present, then you can calculate the electric field using $F$ and $q$. The electric field could be caused by any configuration of charges; it does not matter.
The second one is the electric field at a point a distance $r$ from the point charge creating that field; the field decreases with the distance from the charge quadratically.
Notice that $q$ has different meaning in the the two cases. In the first it is a charge you use to measure an existing electric field, and in the second, it is the charge that generates the electric field.

The $q$ in the first equation is often called a 'test charge', because you are using it to test for the presence of an electric field at a point, and indeed, to measure the field at that point. The $q$ in the second formula is often called the 'source charge' because it is the source of the electric field given by that second formula. To emphasise the distinction it's quite usual to use $Q$ rather than $q$ in the second formula. [So, with that notation, if we eliminate $E$ and re-arrange, we get $$F=k_c\frac {Qq}{r^2}$$ for the force between $Q$ and $q$. This should be familiar!]
